# gradio HTML component with javascript code don't work

Tags: python, gradio

I'm trying to integrate `HTML` file (which contains `javascript` function) to `gradio` HTML component (`gr.HTML`) and it seems not to work together:

Gradio app:

```
import gradio as gr

with open("test.html") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with gr.Blocks() as demo:   
    input_mic = gr.HTML(lines)
    out_text  = gr.Textbox()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    demo.launch()
```

`test.html` file:

```
<html>
  <body>

      <script type = "text/JavaScript">
        function test() {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Hello"
          }
      </script>

    <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
    <button type="testButton" onclick="test()"> Start </button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I run `test.html` it works fine (after clicking on "start" I can see "Hello" in demo id

The HTML seems weird (the button doesn't look like a button):
[image]

And when I click on "start" I'm getting an error on the console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

How can I integrate the HTML file (with js) to gradio gr.HTML element ?

Answer (score 0):

just use html code as string in python
like this

```py
htmlStr = '''<html>
  <body>

      <script type = "text/JavaScript">
        function test() {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Hello"
          }
      </script>

    <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
    <button type="testButton" onclick="test()"> Start </button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

  </body>
</html>'''

...
input_mic = gr.HTML(lines)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Gradio is lacking.

We can inject JS code and actually have it evaluated by the browser by using the `.load` method of Blocks:

```
script = '''
function wrap() {
    function test() {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Hello"
    }
}
'''

with gr.Blocks() as demo:   
    input_mic = gr.HTML(lines)
    out_text  = gr.Textbox()
    demo.load(_js = script)
```

Due to the inner workings of this we need to add the outer wrapper function.

I have found the answer here: https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/3446#issuecomment-1477564504